# Why can I watch videos on Crunchyroll without having DRM content enabled in Firefox?

Tags: web-browser, drm

The title pretty much covers the question. I'm using Linux and, whenever I go to sites like Amazon Prime and such, if I try to watch any of their videos, the player would error out in an error code and claim that it can't play protected content in my browser. A simple google search for that error code will reveal the fact that, for the most part, the reason for it is that I didn't enable DRM content in my browser (and this is intentional, I don't want to install a proprietary plug-in just so I can watch a bunch of videos in my browser).

However, Crunchyroll is the only website I've encountered in which the browser warns me that I should enable DRM to watch the videos but then goes on to play the videos without me actually enabling it at all. The warning it shows is entirely pointless.

My question is: is the content I'm viewing still, somehow, DRM protected or is it just a regular video file which that I can extract by inspecting the HTML code and finding the link to the actual source. If it's not protected, does it appear to be an implementation bug or is this somehow intentional on Crunchyroll's side (maybe as a fallback for people who cannot install the CDM in the first place?)

Comment: It's possible the site only requires DRM for certain videos or certain quality levels.